# Wifi and Bluetooth Monitoring Range

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth, range

Im trying to monitor bluetooth and wifi probe requests.
Im very new in this topic and not sure about a few things:

Bluetooth:

1. Is it correct that the bluetooth class of my monitor device doesnst matter, because just the strenth of the sending devices is important?
2. I want to track mostly smartphones and handfrees (in cars). I heard about smartphones mostly have class II inbuild. This would about 10m range. But i measured the range with my galaxy s3 and it was about 80m.
   So is the range of the probe requests so much higher than the range in specification?
3. If yes, how would you do determine the range of smartphones and or handfrees?

WifI:

1. Same Question, but here with antennas.
   Is it right that the most important thing for the range is the sending device?
2. If yes, how much is the range for probe requests normally by smartphones?
3. Is the Probe Request Range here "again" much higher like with Bluetooth ?
4. I have this wifi monitor antenna:

http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B002BFMZR8

There are two different rods, one small one big.
How do they influence the range?

I Would be very apprechiated if someone could help me out here

Comment: The antenna on the receiving and transmitting devices are both important.  Certain designs change the range in various ways.  Simply and omnidirectional antenna Usually has a lower range than a directional antenna.  Design is a very complicated topic and hard to cover here.  Check some amateur radio sites Article here would be a start http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/library/policy/navy/nrtc/14092.pdf